# Should a class that provides functionality be static or singelton?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, static

I'm writing a C# app, and I have a class that all it dos is to provide functionality to different class I use.
For example a class that provides clock service and more.
is there any reason to make that class a Singelton class? or Static class?
Or maybe it should not be either?

Comment: "a class that provides functionality" is like 90% of the application. Pretty much everything except a basic data transfer structure. And as they all interact with each other they all provide functionality to diffferent classes. Which makes the whole question logically inconclusive - you would not make the whole application static or singleton.

Comment: So why is the Console class (C#) a static class? there are times when you make a class as static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your class needs to keep an **inner state** it should be a `Singelton`, if it doesn't simply make it `static`!

Inner states could be:

- A file reference
- A user preference
- Any kind of history

If it is merely a collection of functions etc.. like `Math`, KISS (keep it simply Static)!